# Intuitive reason behind assuming two regions in a map which touch at only one point are not adjacent while forming the dual graph

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, coloring

I was going through the text "Discrete Mathematics and its Application" by Kenneth Rosen, where I came across a statement which the author of the book assumed while forming the dual graph for a map.

> Each map in the plane can be represented by a graph. To set up this correspondence, each region of the map is represented by a vertex. Edges connect two vertices if the regions represented by these vertices have a common border. **Two regions that touch at only one point are not considered adjacent.** The resulting graph is called the dual graph of the map.

Now I wonder as to why the author had made such an assumption and I found a possible logic behind the same.

[image: Figure 1]

**Figure 1. Map 1**

[image: Figure 2]

**Figure 2. Colouring of Map 1**

Our main aim is to colour the regions of the map such that we can distinguish that the regions are different, without actually drawing a boundary in black(say). In this strategy if we colour the regions which touch at more than one points by the same colour then we shall not be able to recognize that the two regions are different, rather it would seem that they are the same regions. (Figure $1$ and Figure $2$)

[image: Figure 3]

**Figure 3. Map 2**

[image: Figure 4]

**Figure 4. Colouring of Map 2**

Now for the situation where two regions touch at only one point, then even if we colour them the same, then also we can distinguish them as different regions, this is by virtue of the other colours and the single point in common forming a clear(implicit) boundary.(Figure $3$ and Figure $4$)

Is my reasoning right?

Comment: "Our main aim is to colour the regions of the map such that we can distinguish that the regions are different, without actually drawing a boundary in black(say)." Sure, that's the idea that is used in actual mapmaking which inspires the problem.  If you require regions meeting at a single point to be colored differently then there is no bound on the number of colors you might need (consider a pinwheel of $n$ regions touching at a single point.) So the problem is not interesting.

Comment: If two regions are adjacent if they meet at 2 points you run into a similar problem.  They must have a common border to be adjacent.  (We can just assume the regions are polygonal.  Then two regions are adjacent if they share a line segment.)

Comment: That means they should not meet at discrete countable points right?

Comment: Yes, two polygons can only meet in a finite number of disjoint line segments and isolated points.  You don't have to worry about "pathological" shapes. (at least according to the definition given in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_color_theorem#Precise_formulation_of_the_theorem).)